# Need macro to take the parameter in the url to be taken from the cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like the macro to take the **sc_id** parameter in the url to be taken from the cell '[Data Download.xlsx]DATA'!$B$1.
Could you please help me modify the code??

```
Private Const NUMBER_OF_PAGES As Byte = 8

Sub DataDownload()
    Dim URL_TEMPLATE As String
    URL_TEMPLATE = "URL;http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/hist_stock_result.php?sc_id=" _
    & ws.Range("B1").Value2 & "&pno={0}&hdn=daily&fdt=2000-01-01&todt=2015-12-31"
    Dim page As Byte
    Dim queryTableObject As QueryTable
    Dim url As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")

    For page = 1 To NUMBER_OF_PAGES
        url = VBA.Strings.Replace(URL_TEMPLATE, "{0}", page)
        Set queryTableObject = ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=url, _
        Destination:=ws.Range("A:A").Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious).Offset(1, 0))
        queryTableObject.FieldNames = True
        queryTableObject.RowNumbers = False
        queryTableObject.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        queryTableObject.PreserveFormatting = True
        queryTableObject.RefreshOnFileOpen = True
        queryTableObject.BackgroundQuery = True
        queryTableObject.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        queryTableObject.SavePassword = False
        queryTableObject.SaveData = False
        queryTableObject.AdjustColumnWidth = False
        queryTableObject.RefreshPeriod = 0
        queryTableObject.WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        queryTableObject.WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        queryTableObject.WebTables = "4"
        queryTableObject.WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        queryTableObject.WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        queryTableObject.WebSingleBlockTextImport = True
        queryTableObject.WebDisableDateRecognition = True
        queryTableObject.WebDisableRedirections = True
        queryTableObject.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    Next page

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the value in the same worksheet you're adding the `QueryTables` to, you can try adding this line before you're loop.

**Edit2:**

Remove this line:

```
Private Const URL_TEMPLATE As String = "URL;http://www.moneycontrol...."
```

Declare the `URL_TEMPLATE` as variable instead like this inside your sub:

```
Dim URL_TEMPLATE As String

URL_TEMPLATE = "URL;http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/hist_stock_result.php?sc_id=" _ 
    & ws.Range("B1").Value2 & "&pno={0}&hdn=daily&fdt=2000-01-01&todt=2015-12-31"
```

Then inside the loop, use the original code to set `url`.

```
url = VBA.Strings.Replace(URL_TEMPLATE, "{0}", page)
```

I hope we nail it this time.

Comment: Hi L42..Thanks for the guidance. I added the above line to the code. But, the code seems to be not working. Still taking RI as the SC_ID. Plz help!!!

Comment: @SuryaSudarsi What part in the original URL you want replaced? `RI` only? or the whole `RI&pno`. I've tested it and it works.

Comment: I would like to replace RI part only...Each stock such as RI will have data spanning 8 pages...

Comment: @SuryaSudarsi I posted an edit. I forgot to tell you need to adjust the code inside the loop as well.

Comment: After modifying the code, data from page# 1 repeats 8 times. Not sure where the problem is

Comment: After modifying the code, I am getting the following error...Compile Error: Duplicate diclaration in current scope

Comment: @SuryaSudarsi Did you remove the line I mentioned above?

Comment: @SuryaSudarsi Can post your current code? Edit you question and post it there.

Comment: @SuryaSudarsi Put the added line after you've set and declared the `ws` object and before the loop.